# Implementing tree with different data types of nodes

Tags: java, c++, tree, tree-search

I have to combinatorially count all possible cases for a task. I want to make a tree for that purpose. There are several jobs and each job has several sub jobs. There are many agents available to do the jobs. Suppose Job1 Subjob1 can be done by Agent 1 or 2, then Job 1 Sub Job2 will be done by either of the agents. And then Job 2 will be started. and so on.
Since nodes are varying and also the number of child nodes changes at different levels, my questions are:

1. what is the best data structure to implement the same?
2. what is the best way to traverse the tree using the data structure that you have recommended?

please give concrete C++/Java examples or web sources also rather than only abstract advise as I am green at coding.

**EDIT:**

Please refer to the flowchart for the tree that i have in mind.

[image]

Comment: i couldnt post a image due to lack of reputation.

Comment: Then add a link and someone will most certainly edit your question to include the image.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg A helpful image link has been added.

Comment: @gknicker Refer to the link in EDIT section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I don't think a tree is the best data structure for your requirements.  I suggest a `std::vector` of `Jobs`.  Each `Job` should have a container of `subjobs`

Your schedule can iterate through a vector much easier than a tree.

**Edit 1:  The code**

```
class Subjob;
class Job
{
  std::vector<Subjob> other_jobs;
};

std::vector<Job> task_container;
```

Comment: I can iterate easily thru `task_container` like: `vector<Job>::iterator it;
    for(it = task_container.begin(); it != task_container.end(); ++it)`. but how to use `iterator it` to access vector elements of `other_jobs`? Pls give code.

Comment: Iterating through vectors is all the same.  For the member `other_jobs`, you would initialize an iterator, `std::vector<SubJob>::iterator`, to the beginning, `other_jobs.begin()`, and increment the iterator to point to the next element.

Comment: So i will initialise the iterator `it` for the member `other_jobs`  to the beginning as in `it.other_jobs.begin()` or `it->other_jobs.begin()`?